# Convert IloEnv to CPXENVptr

Tags: c++, cplex

I'm building an optimization model with IloCplex using the concert technology.
Within my my routines, I need to call a subroutine that my professor wrote some years back. This subroutine needs as an argument, a "pointer to the CPLEX environment as returned by CPXopenCPLEX". The problem is, that I can't find out how to make such a pointer using the concert technology. The "CPXopenCPLEX" seems to belong to the callable library. What I have done so far, is to declare the IloEnv in my model as

IloEnv env;

Then I try to convert it to a pointer to the CPLEX environment as follows
CPXENVptr cpxenv;
cpxenv = (CPXENVptr) &(env);

but it does not seem to work. It will compile, but when I run the code I the the message

"Segmentation fault (core dumped)"

I hope someone can help me?

Comment: When you cast pointers in C like you are doing, you are simply telling the compiler to treat one data structure as if it were another, it doesn't do any conversions.  The "subroutine" you call treats the parameter like CPXEnvptr, which it isn't.  This gives you the core dump.  C lets you shoot yourself in the foot like that.

Answer (score 0):

The environment has to be initialized, not just simply declared as a local variable.

```
int status;
CPXENVptr env;
env = CPXopenCPLEX (&status);
...
```

Comment: I don't know if I can follow you there. Possibly because I have not been precise in my question. I use the concert technology and start by creating an IloEnv on which everything else is build. If I do what you suggest, my compiler just tells me, that the operator "=" is not matched and there is no known conversion from CPXENVptr to const IloEnv&